# AttributeError: 'PandasArray' object has no attribute '_str_replace'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I'm trying to learn pandas to perform a job that includes a lot of wrangling with text data so I've been exploring the methods available for working with text data. I first encountered this problem by trying to use the .str.replace() on a series, for example I tried using it on a Series constructed using the pd.Series() method, and then I tried extracting a column from a dataframe and using the method on that series. Both times I receive an error that the method can't be called on a 'PandasArray' object. I further tested some other string methods such as .str.contains(), .str.startswith(), .str.title() but receive the same error. I closed jupyter notebook and restarted my computer before retesting the code to check I wasn't using the names somewhere else. I tried reinstalling pandas using

```
conda install pandas --force--reinstall
```

but I continue to receive the error. I checked the version which is 1.1.5 using

```
pd.__version__
```

I am not sure why it's interpreting my series as a 'pandasarray'. The string methods are important for me, but I'm unsure how to solve this. I tried these methods on my personal computer at home using the same code and it worked properly, I thought that reinstalling pandas would fix the issue. Here's the code I tested with multiple times:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
testseries = pd.Series(['Foo','Foh',np.nan])
testseries.str.replace(r'Fo','Ba')
testdataframe = pd.DataFrame({'a':['Foo','Foh',np.nan],'b':['Foo','Foh',np.nan]})
testdataframe['a'].str.replace('Fo','Ba')
```

Error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-0067b28206a2> in <module>
----> 1 testdataframe['a'].str.replace('Fo','Ba')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings\accessor.py in wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     99                 )
    100                 raise TypeError(msg)
--> 101             return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    102 
    103         wrapper.__name__ = func_name

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings\accessor.py in replace(self, pat, repl, n, case, flags, regex)
   1310                 warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning, stacklevel=3)
   1311             regex = True
-> 1312         result = self._array._str_replace(
   1313             pat, repl, n=n, case=case, flags=flags, regex=regex
   1314         )

AttributeError: 'PandasArray' object has no attribute '_str_replace'
```

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue using pandas 1.1.3 (in a conda environment). Got it solved by updating to 1.2.0

Answer (score 0):

In my enviroment `python 3.8` and pandas version `1.1.3` the code works just fine.In any case you can experiment with `numpy` ,where you won't have version issues, for string operations and see if it meets your requirements.

Comment: I tried to install pandas version 1.1.3 but the error hasn't changed. I'm using python 3.7. I'll have to look into numpy for string operations if all else fails, thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Solved. The solution was to go to CONDA and use the command conda update --all and retested the code.